# Adding Font awesome Icon Dynamically to SVG text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, svg, font-awesome

I am trying to add a font awesome icon dynamically to an svg element using JavaScript.

Here is my SVG:

```
<svg id="mySVG"  baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin"  class="svg-map">
    <g>
        <circle id="test-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle id="test-2" cx="150" cy="50" r="10" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have then created a function to add in a text element like this:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";  
function createText(id, cx, cy, size, fill, stroke)
    {
        var seatX = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text"); 
        seatX.setAttributeNS(null,"id", id);
        seatX.setAttributeNS(null,"x", cx);
        seatX.setAttributeNS(null,"y", cy);
        seatX.setAttributeNS(null,"r", size);
        seatX.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", fill);
        seatX.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke", stroke);
        seatX.setAttributeNS(null,"font-family", 'FontAwesome Pro 5');
        seatX.textContent = '&#xf00d;';
        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(seatX);
    }

$('circle').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var cx = parseInt($(this).attr('cx'));
    var cy = parseInt($(this).attr('cy'))
    var x = (cx - 8)
    var y = (cy + 9.25)
    createText(id+'_text', x, y, '10', 'white', 'none');
});
```

The above insert the new text element, but the font awesome is displaying as text, rather than getting converted.

If i manually add in the text element like this then it works:

```
<svg id="mySVG"  baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin"  class="svg-map">
    <g>
        <circle id="test-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle id="test-2" cx="150" cy="50" r="10" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <text id="test-1_text" x="42" y="59.25" r="10" fill="white" stroke="none" >&#xf00d;</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It's clear font awesome doesn't get loaded into the new content that is generated. Is there a way i can get around this?

Comment: Which font-awesome version are you using? Try adding classes according to the docs. For bugfixing, try figuring out what the difference is between your HTML and the Javascript variant, perhaps hidden pseudo elements.

Comment: I am using Pro 5.6.3. No difference at all. One is getting loaded dynamically, one isn't. It's exactly the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`. textContent will not parse the HTML for you.

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function createText(id, cx, cy, size, fill, stroke) {
  var seatX = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "text");
  seatX.setAttributeNS(null, "id", id);
  seatX.setAttributeNS(null, "x", cx);
  seatX.setAttributeNS(null, "y", cy);
  seatX.setAttributeNS(null, "r", size);
  seatX.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", fill);
  seatX.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", stroke);
  seatX.setAttributeNS(null, "font-family", 'FontAwesome');
  seatX.innerHTML = '&#xf005;';
  document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(seatX);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('circle').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var cx = parseInt($(this).attr('cx'));
    var cy = parseInt($(this).attr('cy'))
    var x = (cx - 8)
    var y = (cy + 9.25)
    createText(id + '_text', x, y, '10', 'white', 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" class="svg-map">
    <g id="mySVG">
        <circle id="test-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></circle>
        <circle id="test-2" cx="150" cy="50" r="10" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```